# What happens when I view some element on page with browsers's development tools?

Tags: html, css, browser, opera

For several times I have encountered a strange behavior of our web-pages: if I just open the page it looks in one way, and if I view some element of that page with the developers tools provided by my browser - the appearance of the element changes. It really looks like some refresh event is thrown if I click on some div and look at it in development tools.

Does anyone know what happening?

For example, in my current situation I have some div, with semi-transparent background which should move after some event occurs. It moves in all the browsers except for opera. In Opera the is not shown at all. But in case I check that div with Opera Development Tools the div becomes visible! When I switch to standart mode - it becomes hidden again.

What happens when I track some div's data with development tools?

Comment: Do you not just mean that the development tools are highlighting the element you have selected using the development tool html or css selector? So they're just highlighting an element to show you what you are looking at?

Comment: Yeah I know that they are highlighting the element. But actually SOMETIMES I see another effect: they change the way the element looks. For example, show the element that was hidden before.

Answer (score 0):

This is common behavior of all visual development editors and debuggers. In order to allow editing/debugging of the items, they overwrite the visibility properties of the components to TRUE.

Returning in normal mode, of course will set all properties to its real value.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The thing is that the element becomes visible event if I check another element. It looks like some event of updating or refreshing on page occurs.